# Azure functions with file system trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have a file system that is connected with an Azure Gateway to a VM.
The azure function should receive all new files, and start processing them...

However, there is a file system trigger, but we keep getting the error: the path does not exists.

We have the exact same filesystem that is used by a logic app, and there it does work with the Azure gateway.

How can we get our file system connected via an Azure Gateway and trigger the azure function every time a file is dropped?

Comment: Is this using Azure Functions on the consumption plan? It doesn't have a file system trigger so I'm not sure what functionality you're referring to?

Comment: There is a External File trigger, where you can configure a external file connection. There I have selected the file system described above...

Comment: File system triggers are not yet supported with external files. And yes, I see it in the list of External Files, we will update the UI to remove it for now.

Comment: Please do not remove it, it works now :p

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently use a File System trigger with the External File trigger. It's possible that Logic Apps has such a trigger, and you could call a function from your Logic App.

Comment: You can, although the feature is still in preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working... The problem seemed to be somehow with the connection settings in the function app. By creating a new Function app, we are now able to trigger the function when a file is added on an directory in an on premise VM.